Prefill and Allow Editing of Email Field in Stripe Checkout Session
I'm using Stripe Embedded Checkout for handling payments in my application. I want to prefill the email field in the Checkout form with a suggested email address, but still allow the user to edit it. Currently, I'm using setCustomerEmail in my SessionCreateParams, but this makes the email field non-editable.
Is there a way to prefill the email field with a default value that the user can change during checkout?
Here's a snippet of my current implementation:
Java:
public Session createCheckoutSession(CreateCheckoutSessionParams createCheckoutSessionParams) {
    return Session.create(SessionCreateParams.builder()
            .setUiMode(SessionCreateParams.UiMode.EMBEDDED)
            .setCustomerEmail(createCheckoutSessionParams.getUserEmail())
            // other params...
            .build());
}

Next.Js:
<EmbeddedCheckoutProvider stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
       <EmbeddedCheckout/>
</EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>

I'm looking for a solution that works with the embedded checkout mode (SessionCreateParams.UiMode.EMBEDDED). Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Something like this: Prefill customer email via Stripe Payment Link URL
But for the embedded checkout.

This is not possible, the email address passed on the CheckoutCreation would be read-only.
